# How to return a light box error message from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, lightbox, featherlight.js

I've created a basic form validation script that I want to return an error messages as a light box, rather than using an alert() message. I like the look of featherlight.js, but I can't figure out how to return it from a function? Any other suggestions would be greatly appropriated. Thanks in advance.

[The featherlight.js repo](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/)

```js
function validate() {          
  var name = document.forms['userForm']['fname'].value;
  if (name == null || name == '') {
    alert('Please enter your first name');
 return false;
  } 
}
```

```html
<label for="first-name">First Name: </label><br>
<input name="fname" type="text" /><br>
<button onclick="validate()">Submit Form</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit late, but I think I know what you're after. I've just done a similar thing myself, so I'll put it here incase it helps anyone.

I created a function so you can re-use it elsewhere along with an OK button to close the light box.

```js
function customAlert(message = '') {
  var alertBox = $(document.createElement('div'));
  alertBox.html('<h3>'+message+'</h3><p><a class="featherlight-close">OK</a></p>');
  $.featherlight(alertBox);
}


function validate() {
  var name = document.forms['userForm']['fname'].value;
  if (name == null || name == '') {
    customAlert('Please enter your first name');
    return false;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you cannot "return" it. What you can do is you can trigger a lightbox event when your conditions are match, like this:

```
function validate() {                                   
    var name = document.forms['userForm']['fname'].value;
    if (name == null || name == '') {
        $.featherlight($content, $configuration); // Lightbox for wrong validation
        return false;
    } else {
        $.featherlight($content, $configuration); // Lightbox for successful validation
        return true;
    }
}
```

And of course, you will need to modify $content and $configuration variables as you want as explained here: 
https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/

Comment: I don't understand how I can adjust the $content variable to adisplay a simple message like 'Please enter your first name' for example? Any ideas?

Comment: Please read the documentation for plugin at https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/ It explains content and options to pass as an argument.

Comment: This is what I am trying but of course it is not working :( `if (name == null || name == '') {
         $('Please enter your first name').featherlight('text');
         return false;
        } `